# Do words with "ij" (strijf, whijt, prijs, wijf, lijf, lijk, chijld) relate to Middle English?

Tags: middle-english

Do words with "ij" (strijf, whijt, prijs, wijf, lijf, lijk, chijld) relate to Middle English?

They are used in Wycliffe's Bible, but I don't see them at [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=price) or [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/price#Etymology)

Comment: That's a spelling convention that Wycliffe's editors shared with Dutch writers; it represents the /ay/ diphthong of English. But it didn't catch on in English, only in Dutch. English spelling is political, not linguistic.

Comment: None of those are words in modern English. If they were words *in* Middle English, then asking *do they relate* to Middle English seems self-evident. Or are you asking if that spelling of those words that appeared in that Bible also appeared in any *other* Middle English source?

Comment: @JohnLawler What is political spelling?

Comment: @JasonBassford I would have thought they were all modern English words, although nobody would spell them that way today. Does changing the spelling make it a different word?

Comment: @bof That depends on the word and the spelling. If I write more phonetically and use _ay_ to represent the diphthong /aɪ/, which word am I writing when I write _stay_?

Comment: @JohnLawler I don’t see how that’s a meaningful dichotomy. All codified spelling systems, whether focussed on etymology, synchronic systematicity, phonetics or anything else, are political.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit vague (since Wycliffe's Bible is from the Middle English time period, you seem to have answered the first sentence of your post with the second: these spellings do in fact "relate to Middle English").

The sign "j" started out not as a letter of its own, but just as a variant form of the letter I. In various languages, at various time periods, a convention has arisen of writing long vowels with doubled vowel letters; that convention is the source of the modern English digraphs *ee* and *oo.* The obsolete (in English) digraph *ij* basically comes from the same convention: it's a modified version of a double minuscule I, and represented a "long i" sound. The exact use of doubled vowel letters varied between texts in Middle English: they were not regularly employed in all contexts (often a single vowel letter was used to represent a long vowel), so the same sound might be spelled in different places as *ij, i, y.*

For whatever reason, *ij* fell out of use in English.
As you can see from your list, historical spellings with "ij" mostly correspond to modern English spellings with "i_e", which are derived from the alternative convention of using a word-final "silent e" to mark a long vowel (or in the case of the word *child,* the length of the vowel is just not marked). Between Middle English and Modern English, long vowels came to be diphthongized, so Middle English [iː] became modern English [aɪ].

Wiktionary and Etymonline aren't the places to go if you want a list of spelling variants used for a word in Middle English. The Oxford English Dictionary has better coverage of historical spelling variants.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> That's a spelling convention that Wycliffe's editors shared with Dutch writers; it represents the /ay/ diphthong of English. But it didn't catch on in English, only in Dutch. English spelling is political, not linguistic.